# Count number of opportunities with a % range

Tags: netsuite

I'm new to NetSuite. I am trying to build a formula that counts the number of opportunities that have a Probability of 0% and to find percentages within a range (e.g. x opps have 0% probability. x Opps that have a probability between 1-59%) 
Note: The Probability field is pre-defined as a value - there is no calculation behind this.

Part 1: I have tried the following to count the number of Opps that have a probability of 0%.

```
Field: Formula (Numeric)
Summary Type: SUM
```

I've tried all of the following:

```
CASE WHEN {probability} = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

CASE WHEN {probability} = '0%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

CASE WHEN {probability} = '0_%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

CASE WHEN ({probability} LIKE '0%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

CASE WHEN ({probability} LIKE '0[%]%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

CASE WHEN ({probability} LIKE '0_') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Part 2: I have tried the following to count the number of Opps that fall between 0-59%

```
Field: Formula (Numeric)
Summary Type: SUM

CASE WHEN ({probability} <= '0%') AND({probability} >= '60%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

No matter what I try I keep getting ERROR: Invalid Expression

Answer (score 1):

There are a few points to consider here:

1. The percent character ('%') is a wildcard in SQL, so you need to escape it when trying to match the character literal.  To do this you need to specify an escape character using the `ESCAPE` keyword.  `LIKE '0\%' ESCAPE '\'` for example.
2. However, the {probability} field is stored as a decimal number, so you shouldn't use `LIKE` to compare it.  (You can do so if you also use `TO_CHAR()` to convert it to a string, but that's not really appropriate here).
3. Your first expression should work (`CASE WHEN {probability} = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`) - it should return 1 for the opportunities with 0% probability and 0 for everything else.  I tested it and it works for me.  You should replace the strings in your other formulas with decimal numbers (eg: 0.6 instead of '60%').
4. In your last expression, you have the operators switched, so even after fixing the strings and using the correct decimal values, you will just get 0 for everything.  The expression should be `CASE WHEN ({probability} >= 0) AND({probability} <= 0.6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`  Note: *Greater than* 0 and *less than* 0.6.